# What are the conditions for RG flows to have strange attractors?

Tags: renormalization, chaos-theory

[this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458754/are-there-any-known-models-with-limit-cycles-in-their-rg-flow) served as a great reference for RG flows that can end up with more complicated dynamics than fixed points, such as limit cycles. As far back as K.G. Wilson's 1971 original RG paper, there's been postulated chaotic behavior in RG flows, and numerous specific examples such as these [1](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.61.1320), [2](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.41.5713), and [3](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.89.230401).

The papers on this seem to drop off at the turn of the century, or at least are more difficult to Google, so my question is

"what are the conditions in general for a system or field theory to exhibit RG flows with  strange attractor (chaotic) behaviour?"

Comment: I'd be surprised if a nice answer to this is known.

Comment: @Connor Behan, Forgive my ignorance, are there classic results of necessary and/or sufficient for chaotic dynamics?

Comment: The earliest result is that you need to have more degrees of freedom (coupling constants) than conserved charges. But I don't think that helps much.

Comment: @AndrewHardy It's best to have reference links to abstracts instead of to pay-walled pdfs (and doi URLs should be more future proof than journal ones).

Comment: If classical results help you, perhaps [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68556/75633) is relevant.